# Need to call some custom php in wordpress but don't want to have it overwritten

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to be able to call some php before wordpress loads. In other words, the php actually writes a cookie, then loads wordpress. I can hack into the main index.php file and put the code there, however, I'm concerned that when I update wordpress, the custom code I write will be overwritten. Is there another place that I should be making the php calls that won't be overwritten when I update wordpress?

Comment: Just create a script and load it before wordpress with an `include()`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :) Wouldn't that still compromise the index.php page of wordpress though? So if I have http://domain.com/index.php where index.php is the wordpress call, where would I put the script?

Comment: Put the functionality into a plugin (http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin). As an alternative you can define a function in your themes functions.php file, then hook into WP and fire it when WP loads.

Answer (score 0):

You want to run an action on a hook.

The very first hook to run in a typical request is muplugins_loaded (must-use plugins loaded).

From: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/muplugins_loaded

```
add_action( 'muplugins_loaded', 'my_plugin_override' );

function my_plugin_override() {
    // your code here
}
```

For more information:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: Only problem is that wordpress can not fire at all. I need my code to fire before wordpress even loads.

Comment: @user3348106 This is the correct answer. If this is going to be an issue I'd recommend hiring an expert. There's no need at all to modify any core files.

Comment: Just curious - is your concern that the cookie won't get written because headers are already sent? If so that happens WAY later in the process than this hook.

Comment: Yes mattbeck - that was my concern. Great to know that's the case. Thanks!